# Csv column unnamed headers being written. How do I stop that, it adds the row number on the left whenever I run the program, offsetting index writing

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to replace a certain cell in a csv but for some reason the code keeps adding this to the csv:

```
 ,Unnamed: 0,User ID,Unnamed: 1,Unnamed: 2,Balance
0,0,F7L3-2L3O-8ASV-1CG4,,,5.0
1,1,YP2V-9ERY-6V3H-UG1A,,,4.0
2,2,9FPM-879N-3BKG-ZBX8,,,0.0
3,3,1CY4-47Y8-6317-UQTK,,,5.0
4,4,H9BP-5N77-7S2T-LLMG,,,100.0
```

It should look like this:

```
User ID,,,Balance
F7L3-2L3O-8ASV-1CG4,,,5.0
YP2V-9ERY-6V3H-UG1A,,,4.0
9FPM-879N-3BKG-ZBX8,,,0.0
1CY4-47Y8-6317-UQTK,,,5.0
H9BP-5N77-7S2T-LLMG,,,100.0
```

My code is:

```
equations_reader = pd.read_csv("bank.csv")
        equations_reader.to_csv('bank.csv')
        add_e_trial = equations_reader.at[bank_indexer_addbalance, 'Balance'] = read_balance_add + coin_amount
```

In summary, I want to open the CSV file, make a change and save it again without Pandas adding an index and without it modifying empty columns.

Why is it doing this?  How do I fix it?

Comment: It's hard to conclude anything else than that the input file has those fields, and that nothing in your code is wrong other than incorrect expectations. Please [edit] still to show at least the first couple of lines of the original file.

Comment: Column names become "Unnamed: 0", "Unnamed: 1" etc if the *input* CSV file has no names there.

Comment: You can rename the columns in your dataframe to blank columns (`''`), then write the CSV file.

Comment: Providing proper names to the respective columns, however, is good practice: there can then be no confusing what column is what. Or, since those columns have no values anyway, I'd just remove them.

Comment: can someone tell me why it's written a new column with the row number?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas as you have seen will allocate `Unnamed:xxx` column names to empty column headers. These columns can either be removed or renamed.

When saving, by default Pandas will add a numbered index column, this is optional and can be removed by adding an `index=False` parameter.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("bank.csv")

# Rename any unnamed columns
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '' if x.startswith('Unnamed') else x)

# Remove any unnamed columns
# df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]

# << update cells >>

df.to_csv('bank2.csv', index=False)
```

This would rename any column names that start `Unnamed` to an empty string. This approach should result in `bank.csv` only having your updated cells applied.